# SOAP + Quarkus Reactive response: does Quarkus support XML parsing when using Mutiny return type?

Tags: soap, jaxb, quarkus, mutiny

I don't know if Quarkus support XML (de)serialization while the response is reactive type(Uni/Multi). I used Spring Reactor and in Reactor, the response should always be Mono/Flux to make the whole pipeline non-blocking, from request to client and to the final response. Is this the proper way? I only see examples of returning int/String/List, never Uni/Multi in response.

I have modified the official example a little bit to check this is possible, but I don't get proper response.

```
    @Inject
    private PrimeService primeService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{number}")
    @Timed
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Uni<OutputDto> checkIfPrime(@PathParam long number) {
        return primeService.checkPrime(number);
    }
```

My service:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PrimeService {
    private long highestPrimeNumberSoFar = 2;

    Uni<OutputDto> checkPrime(long number) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(number)
                .map(this::calculate)
                .map(message -> new OutputDto(message, LocalDate.now()));
    }

    private String calculate(long number) {
        if (number < 1) {
            return "Only natural numbers can be prime numbers.";
        }
        if (number == 1) {
            return "1 is not prime.";
        }
        if (number == 2) {
            return "2 is prime.";
        }
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            return number + " is not prime, it is divisible by 2.";
        }
        for (int i = 3; i < Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number)) + 1; i = i + 2) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return number + " is not prime, is divisible by " + i + ".";
            }
        }
        if (number > highestPrimeNumberSoFar) {
            highestPrimeNumberSoFar = number;
        }
        return number + " is prime.";
    }
}
```

When I query like `curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/45646546546541`, I see:

```
Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform of media type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

I have `io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jaxb` in my dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jaxb</artifactId>
      <version>1.13.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I want to:

- configure XML parser features via configuration properties
- be able to convert Uni/Multi to XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Well, I just find that apart from `quarkus-resteasy-jaxb`, I need to    add this dependency:
   `<dependency> <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId> <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-mutiny</artifactId>    </dependency>`</s>

And I see XML response while returning `Uni<OutputDto>`.

So jaxb does the serialization and resteasy-mutiny does the conversion.

No, according to the doc, it is not recommended. Check comment to see a proper solution.

Comment: Let me explain. If you use classic resteasy you need the quarkus-resteasy-mutiny to add the support for mutiny types (Uni and Multi).
However, this is build-in if you use RESTEasy Reactive. If you are on the journey to reactive and, as far as I understand have experience with it, I would recommend switching to RESTEasy Reactive. It can handle both reactive and imperative (blocking) code in a much more efficient way - See https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive for details.